# My code seems to do nothing

Tags: c++

Doesn't do anything, it doesn't even let me input when I call gets(), even my IDE is claiming "statement has no effect".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char userluv[800], fuusd[800], orig[800], key [51], priv [21];
int tempfussd[800], kint, pint, tint[5], c, lame;

//get the basic info
cout << "key? ";
cin >> key;
cout << "Second key? ";
cin >> priv;
cout << "Your lovely text?:\n";
gets(userluv);

for(c=0; c<=key[c]; c++){
    kint += key[c];
}
for(c=0; c<=priv[c]; c++){
    pint += priv[c];
}

//do stuff to your key
tint[0] = strlen(key) + strlen(priv);
tint[1] = tint[0] * tint[0];

//string to int then do stuff
    for(c=0; c<=userluv[c]; c++){
    tempfussd[c] = userluv[c];
    tempfussd[c] + kint;
    tempfussd[c] * pint;
    tempfussd[c] * tint[1];
}

    cout << "\n" << tempfussd[c] << "\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this really is C++, you should use `std::string`.

Comment: Do not discard the result of an input operation like `>>`. It is an error to do so, and you'll be posting another question in half an hour why your input isn't the way you want it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I simply don't understand?

Comment: If you followed @chris's suggestion, you'd also fix the bugs in your code that could let someone easily crash your program in one swoop.

Comment: @Duck This question will be closed as "too localized" because it is too specific to one particular piece of code to be useful for future visitors. However, you should still consider accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three lines are statements without effect:

```
tempfussd[c] + kint;
tempfussd[c] * pint;
tempfussd[c] * tint[1];
```

You may have omitted the `=` after the `+` and `*`?

The statements identified above occur in the loop:

```
for(c=0; c<=userluv[c]; c++){
    tempfussd[c] = userluv[c];
    tempfussd[c] + kint;
    tempfussd[c] * pint;
    tempfussd[c] * tint[1];
}
```

If (as hinted by a comment) the `+=` and `*=` is correct, you could simplify things by writing:

```
for (c = 0; c <= userluv[c]; c++)
    tempfussd[c] = (userluv[c] + kint) * pint * tint[1];
```

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your gets() is getting the \n left from the last input on *cin>>priv*. Make it like that:

```
cin >> priv;
cout << "Your lovely text?:\n";
cin.get();
gets(userluv);
```

the cin.get(); will handle that \n. Check out now.